# Grouping categories into smaller categories in a column

Tags: python, for-loop, grouping, categorical-data, columnsorting

I want to group a column in python in such a way that all the colors are grouped with color, cars grouped with car, and all the other values grouped as others. The number of other values is very large so manually inputting them is difficult. However, the values of cars and colors can be manually replaced.

For example, the column looks like this

```
Column name
Red
Blue
Green
BMW
Toyata
djdjd
dhfh
sher
dhfg
```

The number of other values is very large so manually inputting them is difficult. However, the values of cars and colors can be manually replaced.

The result should be

```
Column name
Colour
Colour
Colour
Car
Car
Other 
Other
Other
Other
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, you mean Pandas df column, when you mention column.

You can make a dictionary, as follows

```
replace_dict = {'Red' : 'Color',
                'Blue': 'Color',
                 .....
                 .....
                'Toyata': 'Car',
                 .....
                 }
```

And then apply replace function to the column.

Like

```
df['Column name'].replace(replace_dict)
```

Comment: Yes for colors and cars I can use a dictionary and replace them but is there a way to replace all the values which are not cars or colors to others without manually typing all the values

Comment: replace_dict = {k: None for k in df['Column name'].unique()} will build you the empty dictionary, so that you don't need to type the values in the dictionary. You can just type the one's you need, rest will become Null

I

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of what type of object your columns are but if you transform your columns into list the following messy script will work:

```
ColoursList = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow']
CarsList = ['BMW','Mercedes','Opel']
ValuesList = ['Blue', 'jfefe', 'bndf', 'Green', 'Mercedes', 'Yellow']
GroupedList = []

for ValueIndex in range(0,len(ValuesList)):
    GroupedValue = ''
    #Colour check
    for ColourIndex in range(0,len(ColoursList)):
        if ValuesList[ValueIndex] == ColoursList[ColourIndex]:
            GroupedValue = 'Colour'
    #Car check
    for CarIndex in range(0,len(ColoursList)):
        if ValuesList[ValueIndex] == CarsList[CarIndex]:
            GroupedValue = 'Car'
    print(GroupedValue)
    
    if GroupedValue == '':
        GroupedValue = 'Other'
    
    GroupedList.append(GroupedValue)

print(ValuesList)
print(GroupedList)
```